# Is it possible to make this Rust code easier to reason about?

Tags: rust, tauri

I'm reading this Rust code and I barely have the mental capacity of understanding what's going on with all the mutexes and handles. It's all overhead to make the Rust gods happy, and it's making it hard to focus on what's actually going on. Take a look:

```
#[tauri::command]
fn spawn(param: String, window: Window<Wry>) {
    let window_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(window));

    // Spawn bin
    let (mut rx, child) = tauri::api::process::Command::new_sidecar("bin")
        .expect("failed to create binary command")
        .args([param])
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to spawn sidecar");
    let child_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(child));

    // Handle data from bin
    let window = window_arc.clone();
    let (handle, mut handle_rx) = broadcast::channel(1);
    let handle_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(handle));
    tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                _ = handle_rx.recv() => {
                    return;
                }
                Some(event) = rx.recv() => {
                    if let CommandEvent::Stdout(line) = &event {
                        let data = decode_and_xor(line.clone());
                        println!("Data from bin: {}", data);
                        window.lock().unwrap().emit("from_bin", data).expect("failed to emit message");
                    }
                    if let CommandEvent::Stderr(line) = &event {
                        println!("Fatal error bin: {}", &line);
                        window.lock().unwrap().emit("bin_fatal_error", line).expect("failed to emit message");
                    }
                }
            }
            ;
        }
    });
    let window = window_arc.clone();
    let window_cc = window.clone();
    window_cc.lock().unwrap().listen("kill_bin", move |event| {
        let handle = handle_arc.clone();
        handle.lock().unwrap().send(true).unwrap();
        window.lock().unwrap().unlisten(event.id());
    });

    // Handle data to bin
    let window = window_arc.clone();
    tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
        let child_clone = child_arc.clone();
        let (handle, handle_rx) = broadcast::channel(1);
        let handle_rx_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(handle_rx));
        let handle_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(handle));
        let window_c = window.clone();
        window.lock().unwrap().listen("to_bin", move |event| {
            let handle_rx = handle_rx_arc.clone();
            if handle_rx.lock().unwrap().try_recv().is_ok() {
                window_c.lock().unwrap().unlisten(event.id());
                return;
            }
            // Send data to bin
            let payload = String::from(event.payload().unwrap());
            let encrypted = xor_and_encode(payload) + "\n";
            println!("Data to send: {}", event.payload().unwrap());
            child_clone.clone().lock().unwrap().write(encrypted.as_bytes()).expect("could not write to child");
        });
        let window_c = window.clone();
        window.lock().unwrap().listen("kill_bin", move |event| {
            let handle = handle_arc.clone();
            handle.lock().unwrap().send(true).unwrap();
            window_c.lock().unwrap().unlisten(event.id());
        });
    });
}
```

Are all these Arcs, Mutexes and clones necessary? How would I go about cleaning this up in a Rust idiomatic way, making it easier to see what's going on?

Comment: This is quite a chunk of code you've included in the question. I think broadcast channel endpoints are both `Clone` and `Sync`, so you shouldn't need to wrap them in either `Arc` or `Mutex`. That will remove a lot of the cloning and locking. Maybe one or both can be removed for `window` as well. You could make use of subscopes and shadowing to avoid inventing new variable names for `window`.

Comment: If you do need `Mutex` for e.g. `window`, I suggest to switch to the mutex from `parking_lot`, which is faster, more memory efficient, and doesn't do poisoning, so it doesn't require the `unwrap()` each time it's acquired. It's a little thing, but it does improve readability in practice.

Comment: Since you already have working code and are asking for ways to improve it, this question would be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For example, based on [this documentation](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.0.0-beta.5/tauri/window/struct.Window.html#method.emit), `Window` is `Send` and `Sync` and both `emit()` and `unlisten()` take `&self`. That means that you don't need to wrap it in a mutex. It's also `Clone`, which might mean that `Arc` is superfluous too (depending on the meaning of `Clone` for the type).

Comment: General way of making method more readable is to hide complexity in subroutines.

Comment: @user4815162342 I don't understand why `doesn't do poisoning` is listed as something good. STD poisoning works as something what allow to propagate panics between threads.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Poisoning only propagates a panic raised while the mutex was held, and forces the unsolicited check on every single lock. If I want to propagate thread panic, there are better ways to do so, such as unwrapping `JoinHandle::join()`. If the poisoning is so important, the panic could have been part of `Mutex::lock()` - I've never seen code that calls anything other than `unwrap()` on it. The [lock poisoning survey](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/12/11/lock-poisoning-survey.html) is a clear indication that poisoning is not a particularly well-received feature of Rust mutexes.

Comment: @jmb, [codereview.se] is only appropriate for code the poster wrote or maintains, and it's not at all clear here whether it has been transferred to asd12tgzxvbgt or is merely being studied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are all these Arcs, Mutexes and clones necessary?

Probably not, you seem to be way over-cloning -- and rewrapping concurrent structure, but you'll have to look at the specific APIs

e.g. assuming `broascast::channel` is Tokio's it's designed for concurrent usage (that's kinda the point) so senders are designed to be clonable (for multiple producers) and you can create as many receivers as you need from the senders.

There's no need to wrap in an Arc, and there's especially no need whatsoever to protect them behind locks, they're designed to work as-is.

Furthermore, in this case it's even less necessary because you have just one sender task and one receiver tasks, neither is *shared*. Nor do you need to *clone* them when you use them. So e.g.

```rust
    let handle_arc = Arc::new(Mutex::new(handle));
    [...]
    window_cc.lock().unwrap().listen("kill_bin", move |event| {
        let handle = handle_arc.clone();
        handle.lock().unwrap().send(true).unwrap();
        window.lock().unwrap().unlisten(event.id());
    });
```

I'm pretty sure can just be

```rust
    window_cc.lock().unwrap().listen("kill_bin", move |event| {
        handle.send(true).unwrap();
        window.lock().unwrap().unlisten(event.id());
    });
```

that'll `move` the `handle` inside the closure, then send on that. `Sender` is internally mutable so it needs no locking to send an event (that would rather defeat the point).